# one computer on win 7 lan is slow to open other network shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I've got a wee lan with 3 computers, each with a variety of shared folders.

All computers can successfully browse, read, and write to all the shared folders.

But one computer ("A") is annoying: When I use Computer A to browse the shares on "B" or "C", there's an initial 5-8 second wait before Computer A will present the requested shares on the requested machine.

During this annoying wait time, the Windows Explorer location bar shows a progressing green bar, during which I can also run "nbtstat -c" and see that the machine containing the shares I'm waiting to browse already has a cache entry.

- All systems run Windows 7 SP 1.
- Computer A and Computer B are ethernet-connected to a WRT54G Linksys router running Tomato 1.19.
- Computer C is connected via wi-fi.
- All systems have Windows firewall disabled.
- All systems run Avira.

***Problem***
only one system ("A") has the browse delay

What troubleshooting tactics can shed more light on this most irksome browse-some-shares delay?

***What I have already tried***

1. I have edited both hosts and lmhosts on "A", adding the ip address of "B". Issue was unchanged.
2. I have rebooted multiple times, no change.
3. I have reinstalled the network stack on "A", no change.